# Donation functionality in flutter

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, donations

I need to implement a donation button in my app.
Initially I want to that users can enter any donation value. But if I use the InApp products in play store, I am not able to set blank values for it.
After researching I found a widget named by_me_a_coffee_wigdet, which seems that I can use for donation. However, it has an alert saying that a donation button could lead to ban my app.

So, what is the best approach to implement a donation functionality?
Is it through an InApp consumable?
How can I use an option in which users can set any value?

Regards,